# Why i cannot apply an !Important CSS rule?

Tags: css

Somewhere within my application i have

```
.table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

By using Server-Side code (at the `ItemDataBound` event of a repeater control) i apply the following CSS classes to specific rows like so

```
<tr id="MyRow" class="fc pwon">
```

Which are...

```
.fc {
   background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.pwon {
   background-color: rgba(77, 144, 254, 0.47) !important;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Unfortunately the color that is applied at the row is `#f9f9f9;`

Why is this happening? How can i fix that?

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` to the end a la `.pwon`?

Comment: Try to make inline.. maybe it work

Comment: Can you provide the table's output too?

Comment: @Adam: There's posting with an unoriginal title... and then there's judging if a question is a duplicate based on its title alone.

Comment: @BoltClock - the answer to this question is about specificity. The other thread states that.

Comment: @Adam: "the answer to this question is about specificity" Not exactly. The questions are completely different; the only thing they have in common is the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.fc` and `.pwon` classes are on a `tr` element, but in your first rule you're applying that background to either `td` or `th`. The background of a table cell is always painted over the background of a table row so you won't see your row background.

You need to replace your selectors with the following:

```
.fc>td, .fc>th {
   background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.pwon>td, .pwon>th {
   background-color: rgba(77, 144, 254, 0.47) !important;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
}
```

It's not clear to me why you have only one `!important` there, but either both of them need to be there, or it doesn't need to be there at all. Remove the `!important` first (because `!important` is usually bad practice if you don't know what you're doing), and if you're not seeing the background, try matching the specificity of your first rule by copying the selector and then adding `.fc` or `.pw` to the `tr` part. This may or may not work depending on the HTML that's being generated; you'll have to tinker with it a little.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are applying `pwon` to `tr` while the `.table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td` is applying style to the `td`.

try this:

```
.pwon td, .pwon td {
   background-color: rgba(77, 144, 254, 0.47) !important;
}
```

Comment: you probably don't need `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

The code that is setting the background is scoring higher on *specificity*.

Basically, although you're referred directly to the class applied to the item, the first piece of code is referring to the table, table body, row, and index of the row specifically, so it scores higher.

It's not ideal, but if you added the other code to the beginning of your selectors like this:

```
.table-striped tbody>tr.fc:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped tbody>trfc:nth-child(odd)>th
{
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.table-striped tbody>tr.fc:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped tbody>trfc:nth-child(odd)>th
{
    background-color: rgba(77, 144, 254, 0.47) !important;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That would fix it for you.  But it's quite messy, and you could look at reducing specificity of the other selector instead, or using an important! declartaion (urgh) ;)

Comment: Actually, the first issue is that one is targeting `td, th` whereas the other is targeting `tr`. Once you change it so both of them target `td, th`, *then* specificity becomes an issue.